# Script or program to log the disk usage

Tags: scripts, disk-usage

I would like either a program or more preferably a way to log the disk usage.

In order to explain what I mean, when someone installs Ubuntu there are approximately 4.5 GB of disk used. Then when you install/uninstall programs this usage increases or decreases.

What I want is a way to log automatically the current disk that is used in a txt file  when there is a change (something is installed/saved or uninstalled/deleted) with the time and date that this change occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `df` command to keep track of the disk space, and the `lsblk` command to keep track of the mounted drives, the script below, run in the background, will log changes in the free space of all mounted drives. It creates a log file: `~/disklog` where it writes changes to (in `k`).

If you run it in the terminal, it will output the result simultaneously.

The content of the log file looks like:

```
[mountpoint / change / date/time / used]

/ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .            36 k       Fri Mar 27 08:17:30 2015    used 87989352 k
/media/intern_2 . . . . . . . . . . .         -1792 k       Fri Mar 27 08:17:32 2015    used 562649592 k
/ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .            -4 k       Fri Mar 27 08:17:39 2015    used 87989356 k
/ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .           -36 k       Fri Mar 27 08:17:43 2015    used 87989392 k
/ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .            -4 k       Fri Mar 27 08:17:55 2015    used 87989396 k
/ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .             4 k       Fri Mar 27 08:18:11 2015    used 87989392 k
/ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .           -32 k       Fri Mar 27 08:18:13 2015    used 87989424 k
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, safe it as `log_diskusage.py`
2. In the head section of the script, set the time interval the treshold and the max number of lines in the logfile:

   ```py
   #--- set time interval in seconds, threshold in k, and the max number of lines in the logfile
   interval = 20        # the interval between the checks
   threshold = 0        # in K, you'd probably set this higher
   max_lines = 5000     # if you want no limit, comment out the line line_limit() in the script
   #---
   ```

   - The `interval` to run the disk-space checks, as it is, 20 seconds
   - The `treshold`: You probably wouldn't want to keep record of all (very) small changes, since the disk has *a lot* of small changes in free disk space. As it is, it is set to `10k`
   - The `max_lines`, since the logfile will grow quickly, especially if you set the treshold to zero
3. Test-run the script with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/log_diskusage.py
   ```
4. If all works fine, add it to your Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time
log = os.environ["HOME"]+"/disklog.txt"
#--- set time interval in seconds, threshold in k
interval = 1
threshold = 0
max_lines = 5000
#---

def line_limit():
    lines = open(log).readlines()
    if len(lines) > max_lines:
        with open(log, "wt") as limit:
            for l in lines[-max_lines:]:
                limit.write(l)

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output([cmd]).decode("utf-8")

def disk_change():
    mounted = [l[l.find("/"):] for l in get("lsblk").splitlines() if "/" in l]
    data = get("df").splitlines()
    matches = [("/", data[1].split()[-4])]
    for l in mounted:
        if l != "/":
            match = [(l, d.replace(l, "").split()[-3]) for d in data if l in d][0]
            matches.append(match)
    return matches

disk_data1 = disk_change()
while True:
    time.sleep(interval)
    disk_data2 = disk_change()
    for latest in disk_data2:
        try:
            compare = [(latest[0], int(latest[1]), int(item[1])) for item in disk_data1 if latest[0] == item[0]][0]
            if not compare[1] == compare[2]:
                diff = compare[2]-compare[1]
                if abs(diff) > threshold:
                    with open(log, "a") as logfile:
                        drive = compare[0]; lt = 18-int((len(drive)/2)); lk = 14-len(str(diff))
                        s = drive+" ."*lt+lk*" "+str(diff)+" k   \t"+str(time.strftime("%c"))+"\t"+"used "+str(compare[1])+" k\n"
                        logfile.write(s)
                    print(s, end = "")
                    # if you don't want to set a limit to the max number of lines, comment out the line below
                    line_limit()
        except IndexError:
            pass
    disk_data1 = disk_data2
```

Comment: This is really great. Thank you! If only I can ask one more thing, is there a way to add the used disk space also? If it is difficult nevermind!

Comment: @Adam Done!  I also "cleaned up" the layout of the log file a bit.

Comment: @Adam It was fun to do! :)

Comment: I am glad because it is useful too! :P

Answer (score 0):

You should use vmstat which is already installed on ubuntu, or iostat but you've to install it.
 [iostat, vmstat and mpstat Examples for Linux Performance Monitoring](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/iostat-vmstat-mpstat-examples/)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with checking disk usage after a package is installed/removed.

Comment: I checked it too and I think that heemayl is right as I can't find anything regarding disk usage, although I am not an exprerienced Ubuntu user. Thank you for your answer though.