# How can I check how much space specific packages occupy?

Tags: apt, package-management, disk-usage

I maintain a list of packages I installed on my system (using `apt-get`). I would like to know how much space these packages occupy, together with their dependencies if possible.

Can I use some tool for it or do I have to write my own script that would sum up all corresponding files (binaries, dynamic libraries, etc.)?

Comment: You need to know it *before* installing? This log script could tell you afterwards: http://askubuntu.com/a/601772/72216

Comment: Afterwards but if I understand correctly the script you're linking will only show me the space after and before installongv a certain software. I already have all these packages installed.

Comment: Ah, I see, that is a pitty. In many cases, it will be hard to say what is what, since many libraries will be shared. It would be possible to script- see a package's size plus its dependencies, but that would therefore not necessarily be equal to the actual change in disk space when it was installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this `bash` script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
all_files=( $(dpkg -L "$1") )
for file in "${all_files[@]}"; do
        [ -f "$file" ] && du -h "$file"
done
```

Pass the name of the package as first argument e.g. `bash script.sh nano`.

`dpkg -L package` will list all the files installed by `package`, we have saved the list as an array. It will include the parent directories too, to get rid of the directories we have done a test `[ -f "$file" ]`, so if the array element is a regular file then we will get the size of the file on the disk by `du -h`.

Here is a test result:

```bsh
$ bash check_disk.sh vlc
4.0K    /usr/share/menu/vlc
4.0K    /usr/share/lintian/overrides/vlc
8.0K    /usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop
4.0K    /usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-openbd.desktop
4.0K    /usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-opencda.desktop
4.0K    /usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-opendvd.desktop
4.0K    /usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-openvcd.desktop
4.0K    /usr/lib/mime/packages/vlc
32K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libxcb_xv_plugin.so
12K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libaa_plugin.so
28K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libxcb_window_plugin.so
32K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libgl_plugin.so
24K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libxcb_x11_plugin.so
12K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libglx_plugin.so
40K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libxcb_glx_plugin.so
16K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libcaca_plugin.so
32K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_filter/libpanoramix_plugin.so
16K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/services_discovery/libxcb_apps_plugin.so
776K    /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libskins2_plugin.so
2.5M    /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so
16K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/control/libglobalhotkeys_plugin.so
20K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access/libxcb_screen_plugin.so
12K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/misc/libxdg_screensaver_plugin.so
12K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libsdl_image_plugin.so
32K /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libvaapi_plugin.so
4.0K    /usr/bin/qvlc
4.0K    /usr/bin/svlc
0   /usr/share/man/man1/qvlc.1.gz
0   /usr/share/man/man1/svlc.1.gz
```

Comment: Very nice +1. Only it doesn't list the dependencies. At the same time, listing dependencies is almost not possible, since many will be shared with other applications.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Thanks..i was thinking about the dependencies too, it would be kind of an infinite chain and also as you mention would not be a good one :)

Answer (score 4):

Could not resist expanding a bit, completely based on heemayl's concept, to make a script with two options:

1. Only output the (total) size of an installed package (but without its dependencies, since dependencies are practically always shared, so which package should have it on its "account"?)

   an example:

---

```
    $ check_size gimp
    6644.1K
```

---

or:

2. Produce a more verbose report on the directories, the files, their sizes and total size of installed files (obviously most lines are skipped):

---

```
    $ check_size gimp --verbose

    Directories:
    ====================
    /usr/share/man
    /usr/share/man/man1
    /usr/share/menu
    /usr/share/pixmaps
    /usr/share/python
    /usr/share/python/runtime.d

    Installed files:
    ====================
    48K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/sample-colorize
    5,5M    /usr/bin/gimp-2.8
    52K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/curve-bend
    52K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-psd-load
    52K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/filter-pack
    52K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/pagecurl
    52K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/video
    56K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/color-rotate
    56K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-ps
    56K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/print
    56K /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/selection-to-path

    Total size:
    ====================
    6644.1K
```

---

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `check_size` in `~/bin` (or elsewhere in $PATH), without language extension.
2. Make the script executable
3. If you just created the directory `~/bin`, run `source .profile`, or log out / in.
4. Run it by either the command:

   ```
   check_size <package>
   ```

   for just the size, or:

   ```
   check_size <package> --verbose
   ```

   for the verbose information

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys

files = []; drs = []; sizes = []
get =  subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", "dpkg -L "+sys.argv[1]]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
for l in get:
    if os.path.isfile(l):
        info = subprocess.check_output(["du", "-h", l]).decode("utf-8")
        sizes.append(float(info.split()[0].replace("K", "").replace(",", ".").replace("M", "")))
        files.append(info)
    else:
        drs.append(l)
try:
    if sys.argv[2] == "--verbose":
        print("\nDirectories:\n"+20*"=")
        for l in sorted(drs):
            print(l)
        print("\nInstalled files:\n"+20*"=")
        for l in sorted(files):
            print(l.strip())
        print("\nTotal size:\n"+20*"=")
        print(str(sum(sizes))+"K")
except IndexError:
    print(str(sum(sizes))+"K")
```